# Run n' Gun game: Fixating the gun's angle

Tags: game-maker, platformer, aiming, game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to have the gun stick to facing the left or right when the player isn't pressing any of the arrow keys. For instance, if the player is aiming diagonally up-left, then when the player lets go of the arrow keys the gun should aim to the left. Here is the code, it is when it starts using the facing variable. Right now it stays stuck aiming in any direction.

```
//Keyboard Aim
key_left = keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_up = keyboard_check(vk_up);
key_down = keyboard_check(vk_down);

if (oPlayer.controller == 0)
{
    var dir = point_direction(0, 0, key_right-key_left, key_down-key_up);   
    if (key_left!=0 || key_right!=0 || key_up!=0 || key_down!=0)
    {
        image_angle = round(dir / 45) * 45;
    }
    //Make it so the gun aims only left or right when not pressing arrow keys
    if (key_right || key_left) 
    {
        facing = key_right - key_left;
    }
    else 
    {
        dir = point_direction(0, 0, facing, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to put your `image_angle = ...` code *after* you update your `dir` variable to use `facing`?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've written here, `dir` is a local variable that gets thrown out at the end of the function. It doesn't store any information for the next frame or directly affect game state.

In order to have a visible outcome, you need to update your `image_angle` variable.

But you only do that in one place:

```
if (key_left!=0 || key_right!=0 || key_up!=0 || key_down!=0) {
    image_angle = round(dir / 45) * 45; 
}
```

And this code is skipped entirely when no keys are pressed.

Later on, you update `dir` to your desired direction for the case where no keys are pressed, but now it's too late.

```
else { 
    dir = point_direction(0, 0, facing, 0); 
}
```

The only thing `dir` does after this point in your function is wink out of existence. Because you don't assign it to your `image_angle`, this code has no visible outcome.

It looks like you want your function to look more like this:

```
// Cache our left-right facing direction 
// whenever it's non-zero.
var newFacing = key_right - key_left;
if (newFacing != 0) {
    facing = newFacing;
}

// Compute our aim angle, using the
// cached left-right facing, and the
// latest up-down input, if any.
var dir = point_direction(0, 0, facing, key_down-key_up); 

// Apply the result so we can see it.
image_angle = round(dir / 45) * 45;
```

Now `image_angle` is always updated at the end of the function, whether we're pressing any keys or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand why it doesn't work now